# Why is にスカウトしたい used here rather than は/がスカウトしたい?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> ちなみ「それより食事内容は大丈夫？」
>
> 逢桜「はい。今はまだ制限もないので大丈夫です」
>
> ちなみ「なら良かったわ。後は味が合うかどうかだけど……」
>
> 逢桜「ちなみさんの料理、美味しいです。正直、桜和亭**に**スカウトしたいぐらいですから」
>
> ちなみ「あらあらお上手ね。ふふ、凪間書店が閉店したら雇ってもらおうかしら」

逢桜’s parents are running a restaurant called 桜和亭 while ちなみ is running a bookstore called 凪間書店. ちなみ treated 逢桜 to a homemade meal.

I wonder why is にスカウトしたい used here rather than は/がスカウトしたい? Isn’t 桜和亭 the subject of the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

No, the (implied) subject of this sentence is not 桜和亭, but 私. The particle に is used because 桜和亭 is the target of the verb スカウトする -- that is, the place **to which** 逢桜 wants to recruit ちなみ.

> 「ちなみさんの料理、美味しいです。正直、桜和亭にスカウトしたいぐらいですから」

means

> "Your food is delicious, Chinami-san. Honestly, it's so good I'd like to recruit you to [work at] 桜和亭."